# Twitter Bootstrap - 940px wide responsive layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm building af responsive website using Twitter Bootstrap. My problem is that I need to keep my layout at 940px wide if the screen is more than 1200px in resolution, but the bootstrap-responsive.css converts it to 1170px. What is the best solution for bringing it back to 940px?

I have tried to remove the hack at "Large desktops (>1200px)" under the Responsive section when customizing on the Bootstrap homepage, but it doesn't supply me with an updated "bootstrap-responsive.css".

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't give you `bootstrap-reponseive.css` because it bakes everything into one CSS file, and it's minimized version. If the only thing you want to change are the widths, you can keep your old CSS file and just adjust them in its source.

Comment: So I need change a number of CSS classes in bootstrap-responsive.css to make the change?

Comment: You can do that, or you can just use the baked CSS file. It should work, since the "responsive" part is there, even though it's in the same file with all the other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .span12, .container { width: 940px; }
}
```